# org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [events0_.id.typesOfEvents] with element property reference [type_id]

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am using spring boot and jpa with restful api. when i am trying to get list of event then this type of error occurs - org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [events0_.id.typesOfEvents] with element property reference [type_id]

I am passing List Object to constructor as args into jpa custom query but that query will not execute it will fire error.

Event is Main entity inside this entity i have taken List of typeOfEvents with using ManyToMany relation and that two table of Id is stored into third table.

1.Event.java

```
@Builder
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public @Data
class Events implements Comparable<Events> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "site_id")
    private Sites sites;

    @Column
    private boolean multipleDays;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "events_types",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "e_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "t_id", unique = false))
    private List<TypesOfEvents> typesOfEvents = new ArrayList<TypesOfEvents>(Arrays.asList());

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinTable(name = "events_format",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "e_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fs_id", unique = false))
    private List<FormatStructure> formatStructure = new ArrayList<>();

    @Column
    private String startDate;

    @Column
    private String startTime;

    @Column
    private String endDate;

    @Column
    private String endTime;

    @Column
    private String eventName;

    @Column
    private String subTitle;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @Column
    private String location;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    private City city;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "venue_one_off_option_id")
    private VenueOneOffOptions venueOneOffOptions;

    @Column
    private double fee;

    @Column
    private boolean paid;

    @Column
    private String eventImg;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_passport_option_id")
    private EventPassportOptions eventPassportOptions;

    @Column
    private int passportTickets;

    @Column
    private int remainingTickets;

    @Column
    private boolean passport;

    @Column
    private int passportDiscountPercent;

    @Column
    private String promoCode;

    @Column
    private String siteUrl;

    @Column
    private String ticketPurchaseSite;

    @Column
    private String videoUrl;


    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "primary_contact_member_id")
    private Members primary_contact_member_id;


    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_member_id")
    private Members created_member_id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
    private Groups groups;

    @Column
    private String expectedAttendance;

    @Column
    private boolean myFavourite;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "eventStatusId")
    private EventStatus eventStatus;

    @Column
    private boolean purchasedPromotionalEmails;

    @Column
    private boolean featured;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinTable(name = "events_audience_types",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "e_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "at_id", unique = false))
    private List<AudienceTypes> audienceTypes = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinTable(name = "events_food_options",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "e_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fo_id", unique = false))
    private List<FoodOptions> foodOptions = new ArrayList<>();

    public Events() {
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(Events o) {
        return (int) (this.id - o.id);
    }
}
```

2.EventDTO.java

```
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM)
public @Data
class TestDTO implements Comparable<TestDTO>{

    private Long id;

    private boolean multipleDays;

    private List<TypesOfEvents> eventType = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList());

    private String startDate;

    private String startTime;

    private String endDate;

    private String endTime;

    private String eventName;

    private String subTitle;

    private String location;

    private String city;

    private double fee;

    private boolean paid;

    private String eventImg;

    private Long passportOption;

    private int passportTickets;

    private int remainingTickets;

    private boolean passport;

    private String promoCode;

    private String expectedAttendance;

    private boolean myFavourite;

    private String eventStatus;

    private boolean featured;

    public TestDTO(Long id, boolean multipleDays, List<TypesOfEvents> eventType, String startDate, String startTime, String endDate, String endTime, String eventName, String subTitle, String location, String city, double fee, boolean paid, String eventImg, Long passportOption, int passportTickets, int remainingTickets, boolean passport, String promoCode, String expectedAttendance, boolean myFavourite, String eventStatus, boolean featured) {
        this.id = id;
        this.multipleDays = multipleDays;
        this.eventType = eventType;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.endTime = endTime;
        this.eventName = eventName;
        this.subTitle = subTitle;
        this.location = location;
        this.city = city;
        this.fee = fee;
        this.paid = paid;
        this.eventImg = eventImg;
        this.passportOption = passportOption;
        this.passportTickets = passportTickets;
        this.remainingTickets = remainingTickets;
        this.passport = passport;
        this.promoCode = promoCode;
        this.expectedAttendance = expectedAttendance;
        this.myFavourite = myFavourite;
        this.eventStatus = eventStatus;
        this.featured = featured;
    }
}
```

3.Query

```
@Query("SELECT new com.test.responseDTO.TestDTO(e.id, e.multipleDays, e.typesOfEvents, e.startDate, e.startTime, e.endDate, e.endTime, e.eventName, e.subTitle, e.location, c.name, e.fee, e.paid, e.eventImg, p.event_passport_option_id, e.passportTickets, e.remainingTickets, e.passport, e.promoCode, e.expectedAttendance, e.myFavourite, s.status, e.featured)" +
            " from Events e LEFT JOIN e.typesOfEvents.type_id t JOIN e.city c JOIN e.eventPassportOptions p JOIN e.eventStatus s WHERE e.startDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate AND e.endDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate ORDER BY e.startDate, e.id ASC")
    List<TestDTO> findAllListOfEventsWithoutEventTypeIdWithOnlyTwoDateTest1(String startDate, String endDate);
```

4.Error

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [events0_.id.typesOfEvents] with element property reference [type_id]
```

Comment: You cannot use collections in the constructor of a constructor expression.

Comment: @Simon Martinelli   Then how to solve this problem please help me. Because I want custom field with list of object

Comment: Why do you nee typesOfEvents?

Comment: which is required for show some field at fronted

Answer (score 0):

You reference `type_id` from list which its not allowed here, because query expression referring `type_id` to list, not to entity itself. So only replace this `LEFT JOIN e.typesOfEvents.type_id t` with `LEFT JOIN e.typesOfEvents t` and it would be work fine. And it would reference variable `t` to element from list(Relation).

```java
    @Query("SELECT new com.test.responseDTO.TestDTO(e.id, e.multipleDays, e.typesOfEvents, e.startDate, e.startTime, e.endDate, e.endTime, e.eventName, e.subTitle, e.location, c.name, e.fee, e.paid, e.eventImg, p.event_passport_option_id, e.passportTickets, e.remainingTickets, e.passport, e.promoCode, e.expectedAttendance, e.myFavourite, s.status, e.featured)" +
            " from Events e LEFT JOIN e.typesOfEvents t /*this fixed*/ JOIN e.city c JOIN e.eventPassportOptions p JOIN e.eventStatus s WHERE e.startDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate AND e.endDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate ORDER BY e.startDate, e.id ASC")
    List<TestDTO> findAllListOfEventsWithoutEventTypeIdWithOnlyTwoDateTest1(String startDate, String endDate);
```

My Query with changes into TestDTO

```
    @Query("SELECT new com.techavidus.networkingPhoniex.responseDTO.TestDTO(e.id, e.multipleDays, t, e.startDate, e.startTime, e.endDate, e.endTime, e.eventName, e.subTitle, e.location, c.name, e.fee, e.paid, e.eventImg, p.event_passport_option_id, e.passportTickets, e.remainingTickets, e.passport, e.promoCode, e.expectedAttendance, e.myFavourite, s.status, e.featured)" +
            " from Events e LEFT JOIN e.typesOfEvents t JOIN e.city c JOIN e.eventPassportOptions p JOIN e.eventStatus s WHERE e.startDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate AND e.endDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate ORDER BY e.startDate, e.id ASC")
    List<TestDTO> findAllListOfEventsWithoutEventTypeIdWithOnlyTwoDateTest1(String startDate, String endDate);
```

output :

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "Record's find successfully.",
  "data": [
    {
      "date": "2020/05/28",
      "count": 2,
      "events": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "multipleDays": true,
          "eventType": {
            "type_id": 1,
            "type": "Musician1",
            "paid_listing": false,
            "color": "Black",
            "_enabled": true
          },
          "startDate": "2020/05/28",
          "startTime": "10:12:15",
          "endDate": "2020/05/30",
          "endTime": "20:18:25",
          "eventName": "Test",
          "subTitle": "Testing demo",
          "location": "string",
          "city": "Bhuj",
          "fee": 49,
          "paid": false,
          "eventImg": "Imgage url",
          "passportOption": 1,
          "passportTickets": 0,
          "remainingTickets": 0,
          "passport": false,
          "promoCode": "TEST123",
          "expectedAttendance": "1500",
          "myFavourite": false,
          "eventStatus": "Pending Approval",
          "featured": false
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "multipleDays": true,
          "eventType": {
            "type_id": 2,
            "type": "Personal Growth",
            "paid_listing": true,
            "color": "Black",
            "_enabled": true
          },
          "startDate": "2020/05/28",
          "startTime": "10:12:15",
          "endDate": "2020/05/30",
          "endTime": "20:18:25",
          "eventName": "Test",
          "subTitle": "Testing demo",
          "location": "string",
          "city": "Bhuj",
          "fee": 49,
          "paid": false,
          "eventImg": "Imgage url",
          "passportOption": 1,
          "passportTickets": 0,
          "remainingTickets": 0,
          "passport": false,
          "promoCode": "TEST123",
          "expectedAttendance": "1500",
          "myFavourite": false,
          "eventStatus": "Pending Approval",
          "featured": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have try with as per your suggest but getting error ----Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class

Comment: /*this fixed*/ - this place what can i  do ?

Comment: make sure you have the valid constructor on `TestDTO`

Comment: But i want to suggest something (If you allowed), repository should retrieve entity as is. do not put convert it to DTO or anything else, you should have a mapper class that can map your entity to dto.

Comment: I have update my your code. but still same id with multiple time shown can i merge it ?